# Is there a better way to restore transaction logs to a MSSQL db?

Tags: sql-server

We're using redgate's sqlbackup to restore external transaction logs from a source database every hour to a local MSSQL db. Currently the local db is permanently in a readonly state with a standby file. I'm not married to this arrangement, it currently seems to me like the simplest way to keep a database up to date if we ship logs every hour.

We restore this db then move some tables to a different, live db during the hour, before the log restore time period, so we can access it anytime. During the restore period we cannot access this readonly database for a minute or two.

Is there a way to keep the db accessible while the log restore is running? Please tell me there's a better way..

Thanks

Comment: Can the source/target servers connect directly? Using availability groups with async readable secondaries can give near realtime replication with no interruption.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Out of curiosity, how did you single-handedly migrate the question from stackoverflow to here? I have tried to do that a couple of times when it's the obvious solution but it seems I lack some privilege.

Comment: The source db is third party. That's exciting how much action happened to get my post over here! So the answer is that I should set up a read replica?

Comment: Eh not sure I necessarily agree Log Shipping is the simplest solution or if AGs are completely out of the question per se. I think we could use some more information about OP's situation. Michael, how many tables are you actually using from the source database after you copy them over?

Comment: Honestly, we've been copying a dozen tables over one by one to a separate db, it takes up nearly the whole hour (40m right now, and i want to add another half dozen tables) - we honestly have been doing it sequentially, so unless we run them all concurrently we eventually will simply run out of time. Also, some tables we can copy a few days over and some we need the whole table. there are several hundred possible tables, source is 80gb in size

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL Server instance of the 3rd party database?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider having two (or more) copies of the database, and use log shipping to roll through them in a round-robin fashion, making each new restore target the place where the next user reads from. This lets users get more current data as soon as it becomes available, without the usual disruption log shipping creates (where you have to kick everyone out of the database in order to restore the next log). I describe this process in detail here:

- [Readable Secondaries on a Budget](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget)

Another idea, if it's just a subset of tables (or you aren't in full recovery or don't have a version / edition combo that supports Availability Groups adequately) is to continuously pump new data to sets of destination tables, using the same kind of round-robin approach as above, to point readers to the latest copy. I talk about this method in the following posts, the last one being the preferred approach I use today:

- [Schema Switch-a-Roo, Part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo)
- [Schema Switch-a-Roo, Part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)
- [Refreshing Tables With Less Interruption Using Partition Switching](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching)

This can be quite effective if you don't want the new version of the data in *any* table to be visible to the reader until *all* the tables are synced, because you can point the reader to all copies of the table in one motion at the end, instead of current where the tables are refreshed in order and joins between them can become inconsistent.

With most non-AG solutions, though, the data can never be fresher than the amount of time it takes to copy.